# Insert a string of characters after a pattern by AWK in all rows

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am a beginner with awk so that question I suppose it's very easy:

I have a database that has 30 columns (fields) and 50 rows for example, and I want insert the string `GT\t` after a known pattern (`/;IMP\t/`), or a specific field (`$9`) in all rows and get a print of all data base to save it.

I guess it is something like the following code:

```
awk '/;IMP\t/ {sub(/^/, "GT\t");print $9}' database.txt
```

An example of the input lines is:

```
1       20509   oar3_OAR1_17218 A       G       .       PASS    DR2=0.16;AF=0.2293;IMP  0|0     0|0     0|1  
1       21618   oar3_OAR1_19435 A       G       .       PASS    DR2=0.16;AF=0.2293;IMP  0|0     1|0     1|1
```

and the output should be:

```
1       20509   oar3_OAR1_17218 A       G       .       PASS    DR2=0.16;AF=0.2293;IMP  GT  0|0     0|0     0|1  
1       21618   oar3_OAR1_19435 A       G       .       PASS    DR2=0.16;AF=0.2293;IMP  GT  0|0     1|0     1|1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown attempts, could you please try following.

```
awk '/;IMP[[:blank:]]+/{sub(/;IMP/, "&\tGT")}1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking if line contains `;IMP\t` then substitute it with GT along with ;IMP value. Printing current line then.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, `t\ ` is a tab, but I dont want substitute nothing, I want add a new field after pattern  `DR2=0.16;AF=0.2293;IMP`  in concrete, but I don't know if in other lines the pattern will change, although the fix is always `;IMP\t`

Comment: @Alejandro, this is actually adding new field(substituting `;IMP` with its own value + new value I meant there) `awk '{if(/;IMP\t/){sub(/^;IMP/, "&GT")} else{$9="GT\t"}} 1' Input_file` could you please do try it once and let me know where its not working?

Comment: I tried `awk '{if(/;IMP\t/){sub(/^;IMP\t/, "&GT")} else{$9="GT\t"}} 1' Input_file`  and `awk '{if(/;IMP\t/){sub(/^;IMP/, "&GT")} else{$9="GT\t"}} 1'  Input_file`, with and without `\t` after `IMP ` and doesn´t work to me. The otput its the folowing: `1       20509   oar3_OAR1_17218 A       G       .       PASS    DR2=0.16;AF=0.2293;IMP  0|0     0|0 ` same as input.

Comment: @Alejandro, could you please do let me know sample of 1 input line and expected output line here?

Comment: I have put the input and the output in the question

Comment: @Alejandro, sure please try following `awk '{if(/;IMP[[:blank:]]+/){sub(/;IMP/, "&\tGT")} else{$9="GT\t"}} 1'  Input_file` once and let me know then how it goes. Once you confirm I will update my answer accordingly then.

Comment: @Alejandro, do you want to change 9th value to new value in case `IMP` is not found? Just asking otherwise I could remove `else` part in my code, let me know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13in this case there will always be `IMP` due to the type of data they are (imputed genotypes), thank you again.

Comment: @Alejandro, sure, thanks for confirming, I have removed 9th field part from my code now, this should be more specific to your requirement, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Also with `awk` this could be done:

```
awk -v OFS='\t'  '$8 ~ /;IMP$/ {$8= $8 OFS "GT"} 1' file
1       20509   oar3_OAR1_17218 A       G       .       PASS    DR2=0.16;AF=0.2293;IMP  GT      0|0     0|0     0|1
1       21618   oar3_OAR1_19435 A       G       .       PASS    DR2=0.16;AF=0.2293;IMP  GT      0|0     1|0     1|1
```

If `$8 ~ /;IMP$/` is true for field `$8` then rebuild `$8`